# Why does my class not find variable out of other class

Tags: php, oop

Im new to OOP, why does my class in a other file not find a variable out of the other class that i include..?
I tried sending the variable $db but it gives me errors.

The first class

```
<?php
//making Database connection
class DBconnection
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        DEFINE("DB_USER", "root"); // username database
        DEFINE("DB_PASS", ""); // password database
        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_opdracht2", DB_USER, DB_PASS); //host & database name
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully";

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
//running the class DBconnection
$obj = new DBconnection();
```

The second class(a other .php file)

```
<?php
//getting the database connection
require_once('DBconnection.php');

//getting the data from the database
class Controller
{
    public function processing()
    {
        try {
            $query   = "SELECT * FROM information";
            $sth     = $db->query($query); //why does it not find $db..
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$obj3 = new Controller();
$obj3->processing();
```

Comment: Because that is simply not how variable scope works in PHP. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You really need to read more about classes and objects. If you want to use it elsewhere, you need to define it as a property. Also, the same rule about scopes from procedural programming applies here - a variable defined inside a function is available *only* inside that function.

Comment: I suggest you read about [Scope of Variables](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp) and [PHP class properties](https://tutorials.supunkavinda.blog/php/oop-properties). There is some usefull info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DBconnection Class, declare a public variable to hold the database connection

```
<?php

//making Database connection
class DBconnection {

    public $db;

    public function __construct() {
        DEFINE("DB_USER", "root"); // username database
        DEFINE("DB_PASS", ""); // password database
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_opdracht2", DB_USER, DB_PASS); //host & database name
            $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully";
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Then in the other class, access it as follows

```
<?php

//getting the database connection
require_once('DBconnection.php');

//getting the data from the database
class Controller {

    public function processing() {
        try {
            $connection = new DBconnection(); #call db class
            $query = "SELECT * FROM information";
            $sth = $connection->db->query($query); //access the db variable created in db class
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```